# Python: editor that has code completion for user-defined objects

Tags: editor, code-completion

Suppose I have two methods in my class, methodA and methodB.  In methodA, I create an object, S, of class X and then I want to pass this object to methodB.  THen, when I am writing methodB, I want the type of X to be known so that when I use it, typing in my IDE, I can just type "X." and see a list of methods and instance variables for S.  Is this impossible in python?

```
def methodA(self):

   S = X()
   self.methodB(S)

def methodB(self, S):

   "S."....#here I want to see all the methods of variable S.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really a question about Python. Rather, it's a question about IDEs.

I haven't seen an IDE that would be able to do what you're asking. Also, given the dynamic nature of Python, it would be very hard to implement such code completion except for some  special cases.

Comment: +1 yeah it's pretty much impossible to know python objects members without running the code

Answer (score 1):

If your IDE supports a [rope](http://rope.sourceforge.net/) plugin you can have partial autocomplete support.

The editor I'm using [(SublimeText)](http://www.sublimetext.com/) supports a rope plugin, then I can type:

```
class Class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = "one"
        self.var2 = "two"
        self.var3 = "three"

    def method_1(self):
        pass

    def method_2(self):
        self.var1 = "one**"     # Autocomplete works here, no need of workarounds


def test_method(obj1_, obj2_):
    # To make autocompletion works here, I start suffixing the parameters with _

    if False:                # Then I define each parameter statically
        obj1 = Class()
        obj2 = Class()

    # Autocomplete now works!
    obj1.method_1()
    print obj2.var1

    # Remember to rename obj1_ to obj1, ...

###
```

Maybe rope supports a kind of annotations to make the above workaround unnecessary, but I cannot find good examples of it.